# Trying to set default value of <option> from local.storage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i am currently creating an API with a login system where i would like my users to be able to update their user information. 
I have a registration page where they fill in some forms and 's which i then post to my database with a AJAX POST.
I almost copied the exact HTML, and jQuery.AJAX for the edit user page and it works! :D
Now i would like to get the data that already exist in the database, and fill the forms/inputs & dropdowns/'s on the edit user page.
i am able to do this by making a variable containing localstorage.get('user').THE-DATA-I-WANT-TO-FILL-IN;
then for the 's i am making a if or else conditional statement, as seen below.

Here is the jquery function with my HTML view for; edit user page.

```
function editUserPage() {

var user = store.get('user');

var first_name = store.get('user').first_name;
var last_name = store.get('user').last_name;
var email = store.get('user').email;
var gender = store.get('user').gender;
var dateofbirth = store.get('user').dateofbirth;
var phone_number = store.get('user').phone_number;
var address = store.get('user').address;
var city = store.get('user').city;
var zipcode = store.get('user').zipcode;
var country = store.get('user').country;
var nationality = store.get('user').nationality;
var speak_danish = store.get('user').speak_danish;
var colleague = store.get('user').colleague;
var task = store.get('user').task;
var genderSelected ='';
var danishSelected = '';
var countrySelected = '';

if(gender = '1') {
    genderSelected = 
    '<select id="gender" name="gender" placeholder="Gender">'
        +'<option value="" disabled selected>Gender</option>'
        +'<option value="1" selected>Female</option>'
        +'<option value="0">Male</option>'
    +'</select>';
}
else {
    genderSelected = 
    '<select id="gender" name="gender" placeholder="Gender">'
        +'<option value="" disabled selected>Gender</option>'
        +'<option value="1">Female</option>'
        +'<option value="0" selected>Male</option>'
    +'</select>';
}

if(speak_danish = '1') {
    danishSelected =
    '<select id="speak_danish" name="speak_danish">'
                +'<option value="danish" disabled selected>Speak and understand Danish</option>'
                +'<option value="1" selected>Yes</option>'
                +'<option value="0">No</option>'
    +'</select>';
} 
else {
    danishSelected =
    '<select id="speak_danish" name="speak_danish">'
        +'<option value="danish" disabled selected>Speak and understand Danish</option>'
        +'<option value="1">Yes</option>'
        +'<option value="0" selected>No</option>'
    +'</select>';
}


var html = 
'<div class="register-text container">'
        +'<h3>You are about to register as a volunteer for</h3>'
        +'<img src="' + RESS +'img/tinderbox_date.svg">'
    +'</div>'
    +'<div class="register-input container">'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="email">Email Address</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="' + email + '">'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="password">Password</label>'
            +'<br>' 
            +'<input id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="first_name">First Name</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="' + first_name + '">'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="last_name">Last Name</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<input id="last_name" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="' + last_name + '">'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="gender">Gender</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<div class="dropdown-style">'
            +   genderSelected
            +'</div>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<input id="dateofbirth" placeholder="Date of Birth" type="date" name="dateofbirth" value="' + dateofbirth + '">'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="nationality">Nationality</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<div class="dropdown-style">'
            +'<select id="nationality" name="nationality" >'
                +'<option value="nationality" disabled selected>Nationality</option>'
                +'<option value="Danish">Danish</option>'
                +'<option value="German">German</option>'
                +'<option value="norwegian">Norwegian</option>'
            +'</select>'
            +'</div>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="upload-image">Upload Image</label>'
            +'<br>'

            +'<div class="upload-image">'
                +'<img src="images/picture.svg">'
                +'<p>Upload image</p>'
            +'</div>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="phonenumber">Phonenumber</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<input id="phonenumber" type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phonenumber" value="' + phone_number + '">'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="address">Address</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<input id="address" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address">'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="countryId">Country</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<div class="dropdown-style">'
            + '<select name="country" class="countries" id="countryId">'
            + '<option value="" disabled>Select Country</option>'
            + '</select>'
            +'</div>'
            + '<script src="http://lab.iamrohit.in/js/location.js"></script>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="zipcode">ZIP</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<input id="zipcode" type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip code" value="' + zipcode + '">'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="city">City</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<input id="city" input="city" type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" value="' + city + '">'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="speak_danish">Speak and understand Danish</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<div class="dropdown-style">'
            + danishSelected
            +'</div>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="task">Preferred work tasks</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<div class="dropdown-style">'
            +'<select id="task" name="task">'
                +'<option value="tasks" label disabled selected>Preferred work tasks</option>'
                +'<option value="fences">Building Fences</option>'
                +'<option value="bartender">Bartender</option>'
                +'<option value="it-work">IT Work</option>'
            +'</select>'
            +'</div>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<label for="colleague">Preferred Colleague</label>'
            +'<br>'
            +'<input id="colleague" type="text" name="colleague" placeholder="I like to work with (name)" value="' + colleague + '">'
            +'<button class="link-register-user" type="submit" value="REGISTER">Register</button>'  
    +'</div>';

jQuery('#main').html(html);
```

Like i wrote, the AJAX call im using to update after the user entered his new info, is also the exact same as from my registration, with the exception of POST being PUT/PATCH. (let me know if i should ad it too, but i dont think its that relevant, beacause it works and is not the prob here)

SO enough introduction (i think). 
Now the actual problem i want help with is that in my  dropdowns, i want to set the value to whatever they chose the first time in the registration and is therefore im my DB. right now i am doing: 
if (some option is chosen) { show the HTML where this option is chosen }
else (the other option is chosen) { show the HTML where the other option is chosen }
but when i have a dropdown like Country where i am getting all the possible options from an external jQuery script, 
     
i cant make a if(){}elseif(){}elseif(){}elseif(){}, for every single option, when there is more then 200 :(

thank you for the help in advance, and btw am fairly new to stackoverflow and coding in general, so bear with me, and let me know if i should share more code, for you to get the understanding of it to help me out ;=)

Comment: You might want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Tell me if i'm wrong, you want to show (selected="selected") picked country right?

Comment: Iknow secelite, im hvnt learned this forum just yet..
you are abseloutly correct Erol KESKIN :)